# Run Xcode Hello World from Command Line

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode

I have installed Xcode and created the Command Line Tool project for "Hello, World!". I can run it from Xcode when I click the little play button.
But how can I run this program from a Terminal window? I can't find it anywhere :(

Comment: Do you want to build from the command line or do you want to run the built binary?

Comment: I meant the built binary but I've finally found it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I meant running the built binary and finally found it in the Standard Path which can be found under

Project Settings --> Derived Data

and there it is in

[project name]-[number/letter combo] --> Build --> Products --> Debug